# How to prove that $\int_{-\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) dx \leq 0$

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = \ln(x^2+1)\cdot e^{\sin(\lvert x \rvert)}\cdot\sin(x)$$
I need to prove that:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) dx \leq 0$$
what I know is that $f$ is odd, thus $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx = 0$ , so I'm left with proving that 
$$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) dx \leq 0$$
Since $\int_{-\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) dx = 0 + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) dx = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) dx$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: What's the sign of $f$ on $]\pi,2\pi[$? What's the sign of $\sin x$, to begin with?

Comment: Yeah I see it now! Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sin x \leq 0$ for $x∈[π,2π]$, and all other factors are positive.

Comment: I see! thank you. Is there a fast way to prove it mathimatically?

Comment: Which part do you need proof on?

Comment: Wait I'm not really sure I get it now that I think of it again. I know that $\sin(x) \leq 0$ for $x \in [\pi, 2\pi]$ but why does it mean that the whole integral $\leq 0$ ? The other factors are positive so there is a chance that it will be bigger than 0 no?

Comment: If it was $\sin(x) + … $ then you might be right. But this is a product, and that means the sign of the whole integrand is now negative.

Comment: Oh now I understand. Thanks!